# iOS: custom UIDatepicker like the attached image

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

Is there a way to achieve this datepicker?

[image]

Comment: what is special about that picker? not a date picker, just a plain   uipickerview

Comment: I apologize for being noob. How can I achieve that using uidatepicker?

Answer (score 0):

just do a normal picker [here an example](http://codewithchris.com/uipickerview-example/) make the data source "Today" and a list of dates formatted as Thu, May 14

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];  
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, MM, dd"];
NSString *dateToShowOnPicker = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]
```

add the dates of of interest on an array and show that

:p